# Vanity URL for Facebook Application Profile Page

Tags: facebook, url

I am trying to set up a vanity URL for my Facebook app profile page. I've seen this on other apps, but when I go to http://www.facebook.com/username, it doesn't give me my application profile page as one of the choices. Is there another way to do this?

Additionally, the first time I tried this, it did give me the admin page for a 'Like' URL inside our app as one of the choices and I mistakenly chose this one for the vanity URL I want to use. Now I have no way to undo this. There has to be a way to release a URL and then re-assign it right?

Would very much appreciate help with these two issues.

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, the first time I tried this, it did give me the admin page for a 'Like' URL inside our app as one of the choices and I mistakenly chose this one for the vanity URL I want to use. Now I have no way to undo this. There has to be a way to release a URL and then re-assign it right?

They're pretty clear that you can't when you pick one...

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no longer App Profile Pages, as of January 13, 2012. This question should perhaps be archived/deleted.